# Print 'Entry' widget input to console

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a project that recommends movies to a user through a GUI. However I'm new to python and tkinter and struggling with calling functions and variable to functions in general, as a test I want to print out two `Entry` widgets to the console. I've tried quite a few different approaches but something always seems to go wrong. Here is the relevant code for this test:

```
class App(Frame):
    def print_it(self):
        print(mn, nr)

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.filename = None
        movie_name = Entry(master)
        movie_name.grid()
        movie_name.delete(0, END)
        movie_name.insert(0, "Enter Movie Name")
        mn = movie_name.get()
        num_recs = Entry(master)
        num_recs.grid()
        num_recs.delete(0, END)
        num_recs.insert(0, "Enter Number of Movies")
        nr = num_recs.get()
        button1 = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.print_it)
        button2 = Button(self, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
        button1.grid()
        button2.grid()
        self.grid()

root = Tk()
root.title("Recommender")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The variables `nr` and `mn` are obviously not being called in print it, ive tried the preifixes `App.` and `self.` but neither work. Can someone indicate to me what I need to do in order to call these variables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Good start.

First, if you want to access a variable from different methods, it needs to be named with the 'self.' prefix.

Second, the `__init__` method runs when you boot, so if you call `movie_name.get()` it gets the value at boot time. You want the value it had when the button was pushed (I assume), so you need to move the `get()` call into the method that gets called when the button is pushed.

Third, an entry is empty when it's first initialized, you don't need to use the `delete` method to clear it.

```
class App(Frame):
    def print_it(self):
        print(self.movie_name.get(), self.num_recs.get())

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.filename = None
        self.movie_name = Entry(master)
        self.movie_name.grid()
        self.movie_name.insert(0, "Enter Movie Name")
        self.num_recs = Entry(master)
        self.num_recs.grid()
        self.num_recs.insert(0, "Enter Number of Movies")
        button1 = Button(self, text="Start", command=self.print_it)
        button2 = Button(self, text="Exit", command=master.destroy)
        button1.grid()
        button2.grid()
        self.grid()

root = Tk()
root.title("Recommender")
root.geometry("500x500")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually fills in a few blanks and was very useful